# Possible to run multiple 2.4Ghz devices without interference?

Tags: wireless-networking, interference

I have a Logitech clearchat headset that runs on 2.4Ghz wireless frequency. I'm thinking of getting a Logitech Desktop Wave Wireless, also running on the 2.4Ghz frequency.

Will I be able to use keyboard, mouse and headset without interference?

Comment: I don't believe that there can be a good answer to this question unless there happens to be somebody with exact same configuration. I did use wireless mice, keyboards and similar devices in 2.4GHz spectrum and generally I only had interference when I made large data transfers from a wired computer to a computer connected over WiFi. No problems in normal operation or Internet browsing. Still, this does not mean that you won't have any problems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Theoretically, it does (that's why Jobs complained about the number of MiFis at WWDC this year), but it doesn't truly matter (which is why two devices on a WiFi network can still operate pretty well at the same time). Unless you have a Wireless Keyboard, Headset, Mouse, Wireless iPhone Syncer, Baby Monitor, Thermostat, TV Remote, and a Robot that predicts your every need
all running on 2.4Ghz, you shouldn't have problems with them.

That said, make sure you'll keep your receipt or receipt email. If you find that it doesn't quite work, you can always return it, and then you'll have only lost time and gas.

Comment: I can confirm that a Logitech Desktop Wave Keyboard + Mouse do indeed work in combination with a Logitech clearchat wireless headset.

Answer (score 3):

Most likely no issue here, unless you have a lot of wifi traffic in your area, or try to type/talk when someone is microwaving a burrito. These devices actually auto-negotiate in the 2.4 Ghz spectrum, finding gaps large enough to send their signal through.

However, if, say, you live in an apartment complex with 8 of your neighbors running wifi routers, you may have issues due to the spectrum being flooded. This is the situation I am in, and I've decided that wires are not so evil after all.

Answer (score 0):

There IS interference.
E.g. as soon as I swap my sound device of USB-Speakers to 2.4ghz Headset my 2.4ghz keyboard light turns off for half a second. I can reproduce that every time.
There are about 1-2 errors a week which I cant reproduce which may come from that issue to ingame (commands/inputs not comming through e.g.) but all in all no major interferences.
Still with that knowledge I would stick to a wired keyboard with 2 2.4ghz devices (mouse and headset) max. Maybe its my environment or it doesnt even have to do with frequencies,